# How to break down a number with another from list?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm a bit confused on how to approach this problem. I know what I want to do but can't wrap my head on how to logically solve this problem.
say I have a list:

```
numlist = [10,4]
```

and I have the following values in another list:

```
datalist = [10,5,4,2,1]
```

how do I break down the numbers in `numlist` using only numbers from `datalist`?

An example of an answer would be:

```
10, 4
10, 2,2
10, 2,1,1
10, 1,1,1,1
5,5, 4
5,5, 2,2
```

...and so on.

I understand how to do this vaguely.  make a for loop, for each entry in the list and compare if it can be divided by the datalist, and if so print the result.  I think I need recursions which is where I'm having trouble understanding.

here's my code so far (I have some print statements for troubleshooting):

```
def variableRecursion(self, solutionList):
    #solution list contrains ['red', 2, 'green', 1] which means 2 reds(value 4) and 1 green(value 2)

    #adding fake lookup list for now, in real code, I can use real data because I am reversing the order
    list = [('red', 4), ('green', 2), ('blue', 1) ]
    for x1, x2 in zip(solutionList[::2], solutionList[1::2]):
        for x in list:
            for y1, y2 in zip(x[::2], x[1::2]):
                #print x1, x2
                keyName = x1
                keyShares = x2
                keyValue = lookup.get_value(x1)
                if ((keyValue%y2) == 0) and (keyValue != y2):
                    tempList = []
                    #print 'You can break ', keyName, keyValue, ' with ', y1, y2, ' exactly ', keyValue/x2, ' times.'
                    #newKeyShares = keyShares - 1
                    for a1, a2 in zip(solutionList[::2], solutionList[1::2]):
                        #print a1, a2
                        print 'You can break ', keyName, keyValue, ' with ', y1, y2, ' exactly ', keyValue/y2, ' times.'
                        newKeyShares = keyShares - 1
                        print 'there is a match', a1, a2, ' but we will change the shares to ', newKeyShares
                        print a1
                        if (a1 == keyName):
                            print 'a'
                            tempList.append([(keyName), (newKeyShares)])
                        elif (a1 == y1):
                            print 'b'
                            tempList.append([(y1), (a2+keyValue/y2)])
                        else:
                            print 'c'
                            try:
                                tempList.append([(y1), (a2+keyValue/y2)])
                            except e:    
                                tempList.append([(a1), (a2)])
                    print tempList
                    appendList.appendList(tempList)
                    tempList = []
                    #exit()
                    #print solutionList
```

Comment: I don't understand your example. Please make it look like Python data and explain the algorithm a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jochen. I'm sorry, I didn't put some of the sample output in a good code format.  I did that and I think it should hopefully show the correct output I am going for.  Is there anything I can help clarify?

Comment: @Lostsoul.  Define 'break down'.  How does `10, 4` turn in to `10, 2,2`?

Comment: Hi Steven.  It gets broken down each number at a time based on what's in the datalist. so 10 + 4 = 14.  Using the datalist, we can see 4 can be divided by 2 exactly twice so the 4 is replaced by 2 * 2 and the 2 can be broken down by two 1's and so on..as long as it still equals 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is very similar to [Problem 31](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=31) of Project Euler: "How many different ways can £2 be made using any number of coins?". Only in your example, you are asking to enumerate all the ways you can add up numbers to get 10 and 4.

The best way to approach the problem is to first try breaking up only a single number. Let's look at the possible breakups for five, using numbers [5,4,2,1]:

```
[5]
[4,1]
[2,2,1]
[2,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1]
```

The following python code will give you a list of these combinations:

```
def possibleSplits(value,validIncrements):
    ret = []
    for increment in validIncrements:
        if increment > value:
            continue
        if increment == value:
            ret.append([increment])
            continue
        if increment < value:
            remainder = value - increment
            toAdd = possibleSplits(remainder, validIncrements)
            for a in toAdd:
                ret.append([increment] + a)
    return ret
```

This code assumes that different orderings of otherwise identical answers should be treated as distinct. For example, both [4,1] and [1,4] will appear as solutions when you split 5. If you prefer, you can constrain it to only have answers that are numerically ordered (so [1,4] appears but not [4,1])

```
def orderedPossibleSplits(value, validIncrements):
    ret = []
    splits = possibleSplits(value, validIncrements)
    for value in splits:
        value.sort()
        if value not in ret:
            ret.append(value)
    return ret
```

Now you can use this to find the possible splits for 10, and the possible splits for 4, and combine them:

```
increments = [10, 5, 4, 2, 1]
tenSplits = orderedPossibleSplits(10, increments)
fourSplits = orderedPossibleSplits(4, increments)
results = []
for tenSplit in tenSplits:
    for fourSplit in fourSplits:
        results.append(tenSplit + fourSplit)
```

edit: As noted in the comments, calling possibleSplits with a value of 100 is very slow - upwards of ten minutes and counting. The reason this occurs is because possibleSplits(100) will recursively call possibleSplits(99), possibleSplits(98), and possibleSplits(96), each of which call three possibleSplits of their own, and so on. We can approximate the processing time of possibleSplits(N) with datalist[1,2,4] and large N as

processingTime(N) = C + processingTime(N-1) + processingTime(N-2) + processingTime(N-4)

For some constant time C.

So the relative time for possibleSplits is

```
N     1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 ... 20    ... 98                         | 99                         | 100 
Time  1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 7 ... 69748 ... 30633138046209681029984497 | 56343125079040471808818753 | 103631163705253975385349220
```

Supposing possibleSplits(5) takes 7 ns, possibleSplits(100) takes about 3 * 10^9 years. This is probably an unsuitably long time for most practical programs. However, we can reduce this time by taking advantage of memoization. If we save the result of previously calculated calls, we can get linear time complexity, reducing possibleSplits(100) to 100 ns.

The comments also noted that the expected value of orderedPossibleSplits(100) has about 700 elements. possibleSplits(100) will therefore have a much much larger number of elements, so it's impractical to use it even with memoization. Instead, we'll discard it and rewrite orderedPossibleSplits to use memoization, and to not depend on possibleSplits.

```
#sorts each element of seq and returns it
def orderedInnerLists(seq):
    return map(sorted, seq)

#returns a copy of seq with duplicates removed
def removeDuplicates(seq):
    ret = []
    for value in seq:
        if value not in ret:
            ret.append(value)
    return ret

memoizedResults = {}
def orderedPossibleSplits(value,validIncrements):
    memoizeKey = (value, tuple(validIncrements))
    if memoizeKey in memoizedResults:
        return memoizedResults[memoizeKey]
    ret = []
    for increment in validIncrements:
        if increment > value:
            continue
        if increment == value:
            ret.append([increment])
            continue
        if increment < value:
            remainder = value - increment
            toAdd = orderedPossibleSplits(remainder, validIncrements)
            for a in toAdd:
                ret.append([increment] + a)
    memoizeValue = removeDuplicates(orderedInnerLists(ret))
    memoizedResults[memoizeKey] = memoizeValue
    return memoizeValue
```

On my machine, orderedPossibleSplits(100, [1,2,4]) takes about ten seconds - much improved from our original three billion year run time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example.  I'm a bit new to this so I'm trying to figure out what its doing.  I get the logic for the tenSplit/fourSplit, but how can I use it if the splits keep changing.  like in the example, I had 2 varibles(10,4) but in theory I could have 100 variables to split.  Would it work if I created a class and then sent each variable of a list into that class to split then add them all together in the end?

Comment: also..you're code is very clean and made me realize how messy mine is.  Thanks for the example of clean code.

Comment: `itertools.product` can be used to simulate the nested for loops at the end of Kevin's answer.  So for example if your 100 variables are in the list `lst`, you could do `itertools.product(*[orderedPossibleSplits(x, increments) for x in lst])`.  This will return a generator with the results in it.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work but I had a question.  The original way I was doing this, was a brute force method and it worked but after a large number of variables it slowed down.  I thought this approach would be faster(instead of brute force to break down the numbers), but I don't understand why this recursion is taking longer than the brute force(brute force with increments of [4,2,1] and sum of 100 gave about 650 results within a second but the above method is still running after 10 minutes.  There's only 1 nested for loop so I'm not sure what's making this slower than the brute force

Comment: It's slow because it's recursive and calls itself many times within the loop. If you call possibleSplits with a value of 10, it will recursively call possibleSplits with values 9,8,7...2,1. Each of those calls will also make many calls themselves, and so on. However, you can reduce the run time for large values by memoizing past results. [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52201-memoizing-cacheing-function-return-values/) is a recipe that may be useful.

Comment: @Lostsoul - sorry for not pointing out the computational complexity of the original algorithm - it's a bit worse than the notoriously slow fibonacci function. I've edited in a discussion of the expected run time, and gave a faster solution.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you so much.  I did a quick test and seems amazing.  I will test it with larger number(maybe in the thousands and many variables to choose from), hopefully I don't grow old waiting for it(well..older).  I had a question, how do I call this? I added print statements to output (print memoizeValue but print orderedPossibleSplits(100, [1,2,4]) doesn't work)